# Formulating Least Square Problems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a matrix A and a vector b such that the problem can be expressed as

minimize $||Ax - b||^2$

Minimize $9x^Tx + ||Bx-d||^2$ where $p$ x $n$ matrix $B$ and the p-vector $d$ are given.

How would I attempt this problem ? I

Comment: I would try to find the solution $x^*$ of $\min 9x^Tx +x^TB^TBx-d^TBx-x^TB^Td+d^Td$ by the first order necessary condition (grad == 0) and then try to find $A$ and $b$

Comment: I'm not sure I know what first order necessary condition is.

Comment: The gradient (often denoted $\nabla$) of your objective function must be zero in $x^*$ if $x^*$ is a minimum (i.e. $\nabla f(x^*)=0$). This is equivalent to $f'(x)=0$ in the one dimensional case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the norm in question is Frobenius norm, the gradient vector is $18x+2B^T(Bx-d)$. Therefore the only critical point is $x=(9I+B^TB)^{-1}B^Td$. Since the objective function is unbounded above, the critical point is the global minimiser.

Alternatively, let $P=9I+B^TB$. Then
\begin{aligned}
9x^Tx+\|Bx-d\|^2
&=x^TPx-x^TB^Td-d^TBx+d^Td\\
&=\|P^{1/2}x-P^{-1/2}B^Td\|^2+\text{constant}.
\end{aligned}
Therefore it is minimised at $x=P^{-1}B^Td$.

Comment: What would matrix A and vector b be ?

Answer (score 0):

Think of the least-squares minimization $||Ax-b||^2$ as trying to approximately solve the matrix equation $Ax=b$ with small error.  Now consider this system of two matrix equations:
\begin{align}
3x &= 0\\
Bx &= d
\end{align}
Can you rewrite this as one matrix equation in terms of $x$?

Comment: will it be A = [3,b] B = [0,d]?

Comment: Yes, except your $B$ should be $b$.  Be sure to explicitly state the sizes of $A$ and $b$.